# Can we use selenium with No headless mode in production environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, google-chrome

Is it true that we can use selenium only with headless mode in production environment?
I would like to manipulate browser and see tennis court avalilablity.
It is because it is troublesoume to input what is needed everytime I want to see the availablity.

If it is true, how can I manipulate browser and show the avaliablity with browser automatically on production environment?

Comment: Care to share the relevant parts of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Usually backend works on servers without GUI

Just add option if it is production mode

```
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
options.add_argument('--headless') if Rails.env.production?
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome, options: options)
```

Or may be check if it is development mode

```
options.add_argument('--headless') unless Rails.env.development?
```

In this case headless mode will be used in all environments except dev